# How can I open a user's camera and have it open, but NOT to take a photo on Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I want to open the camera but not in photo form so I can add an overlay. I just need the camera to display what is shows but not to take the photo if that makes sense... How can I do this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [this article](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect#kotlin) help you open camera view in your app by creating your own view and open camera in its own different thread,
as it might take time to load and this will result in the lagging UI.

Comment: 404 on that link.